# c++ variables - I tried to compile this program manually but it does't seem

Tags: c++

I tried to compile this program manually but it does't seem to work I need someone to show me what the final result is including the execution of the program ( i am looking for the execution table )

```
  int g = 0 ;

   int fun1(int a, int b)
    {
     int m = a % b;
     return m; 
    }
    int ggT( int a, int b)
    {
     g = g + a ;
     int Null = 0;
        if (b == Null) 
      return a;
          else 
     return  ggT(b , a_mod_b);
     }

      int main(void)
          int a = 7;
          int b = 14;
             {
               int a = 7 ;
               int g = ggT( b, a);
               b = g;
            }
         a = g; 
       return 0;

       }
```

Comment: If the code is not compiling you should include the compiler warnings/errors

Comment: no it ist compiling , but i want it  manually on the papers execution table

Comment: Then it sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: int b = 14;
             {
               int a = 7 ;
               int g = ggT( b, a);
               b = g;
            }

Comment: what does that means ???

Comment: What do you mean by "execution table" and compiling "manually"?

Comment: It looks like an exercise in determining lexical scope when you have several variables with the same name. Follow the braces to see what goes where.

Comment: @molbdnilo this code is from the Uni , i should see what will haben in the end with each variable , this ist what i mean by exe table . i don't what what it mean in english .

Comment: `int Null = 0;` Why on Earth? You got this code from your "university people"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code isnt compiling because you write things were you shouldnt like you tried to declare a method inside a method, it can be done but is not that way, so the problem is that you declared methods inside other methods

And others errors like tried to use modulus as *mod* while it is a%b

More or like it will be like that:

```
int g = 0;

int fun1(int a, int b)
{
    int m = a % b;
    return m;
}

int ggT(int a, int b)
{
    g += a;
    if (b == 0)
        return a;
    else
        return  ggT(b, a%b);
}

int main()
{
    int a = 7;
    int b = 14;
    int g = ggT(b, a);
    b = g;
    a = g;
}
```

It is fixed of errors but i dont know if it is what you want to do or get the answer you want

At final, b and a get g value, wich it is 7, so it is a maximun comun divisor algorithm? Looks like

Comment: You have changed `main` - the original uses the global `g` for the final assignment.

Comment: thank you @jaun , but i did not wrote the code , it's from the Uni

Comment: No problem, see you next time